# Image editing on webpage with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, image-editing

I'm building a website in which I want the user to be able to edit an uploaded image - not the Photoshop style of complicated editing (filtering, corrections etc.), but only "simple" things, like adding some text on the picture (a text-box), or some lines etc.

Does anybody know a jQuery plugin or alike that I can use to do that?

Thanks a lot,

Danny

Comment: You should look at 'canvas' in HTML5

Comment: i don't think there is any plugin but you can do it by combination of jquery and php because php can do complex things like cropping, resizing, merging and much more things! search wideimage in google. it is a php library!

Comment: I haven't tried nothing yet. Also, I don't use HTML5, cause I have to deal also with some lousy browsers like IE7,IE8.

Comment: @Dan So you have to do it server side using e.g php

Comment: Have a look at http://fabricjs.com/image-filters/

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://www.pixastic.com/ but I'm not sure if that'll work with IE7